# adding many shapes triggered from button in fabricjs library

Tags: javascript, geometry, fabricjs, shapes, drawrectangle

i'am making a draw application using fabricjs library where there is a button for each shape to create the question is how to write the code so that each time click on button create shape and added to the canvas as many as he click ,, i.e if i want five circles i will click on the circle button five times ans so on ....i'am making a draw application using fabricjs library where there is a button for each shape to create the question is how to write the code so that each time click on button create shape and added to the canvas as many as he click ,, i.e if i want five circles i will click on the circle button five times ans so on ....

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="Scripts\jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script> 
  <script src="Scripts\fabric.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    $("#addCircle").click(function(){
           canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
     }));
      });

 });

</script>
  </head>
   <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
<div id="editor">
<input type="button" id="addCircle" value="Add Circle"></div>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps